# MySql 8 composite index with the indexed expression "is not null" not being used

Tags: mysql, indexing

I'm using Mysql 8.0.33.

I created a composite index with the expression `column_name is not null` and can't get the index to be used.

What am I doing wrong?

```
CREATE TABLE appointments 
(
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id INT NOT NULL,
  recurrence_rule VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE INDEX idx1
ON appointments ((recurrence_rule IS NOT NULL), user_id);

explain analyze select * from appointments where user_id = 7 and recurrence_rule is not null;
```

> -> Filter: ((appointments.user_id = 7) and (appointments.recurrence_rule is not null)) (cost=150.25 rows=135) (actual time=0.356..0.625 rows=4 loops=1) -> Table scan on appointments (cost=150.25 rows=1500) (actual time=0.143..0.528 rows=1500 loops=1)

#### Details on use case

I have a database table that contains millions of appointments. Some of these appointments repeat (let's say 1% of them) and are defined by a repeating pattern.

I would like to efficiently query all appointments that belong to a user and are of the repeating type. A user might have 10,000 appointments where 100 are of the repeating type.

To this end, I created a composite index on the expression `recurrence_rule is not null` and on `user_id`. But, this index is not used. In particular, it doesn't seem like I can get the `recurrence_rule is not null` to match with the index.

#### Generate sample data

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE GenerateData()
BEGIN
    -- Declare variables
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1; -- Loop counter
    DECLARE user_id INT;
    DECLARE recurrence_rule VARCHAR(255);
    
    -- every 25 appointments is a recurring appointment
    -- each user gets 100 appointments
    WHILE i <= 1500 DO
        SET user_id = CEIL(i / 100.0); -- Calculate user_id, ensure it's rounded up
        
        -- Check if the appointment is recurring
        IF i % 25 = 0 THEN
            SET recurrence_rule = CONCAT('FREQ=', ELT(FLOOR(1 + RAND() * 4), 'DAILY', 'WEEKLY', 'MONTHLY', 'YEARLY'), ';INTERVAL=', FLOOR(1 + RAND() * 10));
        ELSE
            -- Set recurrence_rule to NULL for non-recurring appointments
            SET recurrence_rule = NULL;
        END IF;
        
        -- Insert data into appointments table
        INSERT INTO appointments (user_id, recurrence_rule)
        VALUES (user_id, recurrence_rule);
        
        -- Increment the loop counter
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
    
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

```
call GenerateData;
```

Comment: Suggest you file a bug with bugs.mysql.com

Comment: Thanks! I filed: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=113570

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexed expressions is a new feature in Mysql8. I believe the reported behavior is a bug.

I've [reported the bug to Oracle](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=113570) and will edit this answer when I see a response.

A workaround is to use a prefix index, keeping the index small. i.e.

```
CREATE INDEX idx1
ON appointments (user_id, recurrence_rule(1));
```

(Thanks @RickJames for the assistance!)

Answer (score 1):

I think (without proof) that this would be a better index:

```
INDEX(user_id, recurrence_rule)  -- idx3
```

{ "query_block": { "select_id": 1, "cost_info": { "query_cost": "1.15" }, "table": { "table_name": "appointments", "access_type": "range", "possible_keys": [ "idx3", "idx2" ], "key": "idx3", "used_key_parts": [ "user_id", "recurrence_rule" ], "key_length": "1027", "rows_examined_per_scan": 4, "rows_produced_per_join": 4, "filtered": "100.00", "using_index": true, "cost_info": { "read_cost": "0.75", "eval_cost": "0.40", "prefix_cost": "1.15", "data_read_per_join": "4K" }, "used_columns": [ "id", "user_id", "recurrence_rule" ], "attached_condition": "((`test`.`appointments`.`user_id` = 7) and (`test`.`appointments`.`recurrence_rule` is not null))" } } }

Note the "used_key_parts",, "key_length", and "rows_examined"

You could also try (but it does not seem as good):

```
INDEX(user_id, (recurrence_rule IS NOT NULL))
```

Comment: Changing the order of the index so that user_id is first did not help either. (I like this ordering better actually, but used the other ordering in my post so as to make it crystal clearer that the index was not being used. This ordering will have MySql partially use the index for matching just on the user_id part; but it still won't match on the `recurrence_rule is not null` part.

Comment: @FelixLivni - Please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` and `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT ...`

Comment: The vanilla form is in my original post. Here's with FORMAT=JSON: 
{ "query_block": { "select_id": 1, "cost_info": { "query_cost": "150.25" }, "table": { "table_name": "appointments", "access_type": "ALL", "rows_examined_per_scan": 1500, "rows_produced_per_join": 134, "filtered": "9.00", "cost_info": { "read_cost": "136.75", "eval_cost": "13.50", "prefix_cost": "150.25", "data_read_per_join": "137K" }, "used_columns": [ "id", "user_id", "recurrence_rule" ], "attached_condition": "((`test`.`appointments`.`user_id` = 7) and (`test`.`appointments`.`recurrence_rule` is not null))" } } }

Comment: If helpful, here is a dbfiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xs4isS79x1pBQg8Noc82ZZ/1

Comment: @FelixLivni - `INDEX(user_id, recurrence_rule)` is the winner; I added the format=json as evidence.@FelixLivni

Comment: yes, that works. That is what I have currently in my production database. But this approach does not use the indexed expression and thereby creates a much larger index than I need (since it is indexing the entire recurrence_rule varchar). (I'm guessing I could index just the first character of the recurrence_rule, but have not tested this.)

Comment: Ah, a prefix index works. I.e. INDEX(user_id, recurrence_rule(1));

I'd still like to know why the indexed expression does not, though. But, I think in practice I can just use the prefix index of length 1.

Comment: I filed a bug as you suggested. If you update your answer to include (1) We think the behavior reported is probably a bug and (2) using INDEX(user_id, recurrence_rule(1)) is a workaround, then I will accept. Or I can post this as an answer.

Comment: @FelixLivni - True, the physical size of the index is important.  However, it is [usually] only of minor concern.  I avoid "prefix" indexes like the plague.  But you discovered that it works well for _your case_.  Provide that Answer and approve it.  (I'll be happy with a measly upvote.)

Comment: These queries happen with high frequency. I worry about in-memory caching / working-set. Memory is always our bottleneck. Let's say I create the index as you proposed INDEX(user_id, recurrence_rule) with selects following the pattern as described ... I'm not exactly sure how this would be cached. But I'm guessing the oft-used pages of the index are cached, and this would include the entire recurrence_rule which can be large. So, I'm guessing the smaller index would matter. But perhaps it gets cached in some other way?

Comment: @FelixLivni - If you want to discuss caching (etc), start a new Question with RAM size, `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, `SHOW TABLE STATUS`,, `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, the average size of `recurrence_rule`, and a few queries.  I will be happy to walk through the caching issues.  I will discuss how "locality of reference" does or does not get involved.